# (SVG) Is it possible to have multiple instances of <object>?

Tags: html, svg

I want to embed SVGs via `<object>`-tag (with `<img>` inside for backwards compatibility).

```
<object type="image/svg+xml" data="/res/qm.svg"></object>
<object type="image/svg+xml" data="/res/valid.svg"></object>

<object type="image/svg+xml" data="/res/qm.svg"></object>
<object type="image/svg+xml" data="/res/valid.svg"></object>

<object type="image/svg+xml" data="/res/qm.svg"></object>
<object type="image/svg+xml" data="/res/valid.svg"></object>

<object type="image/svg+xml" data="/res/qm.svg"></object>
<object type="image/svg+xml" data="/res/valid.svg"></object>
```

Now I've notice that if I want to use a picture multiple times on the page it will be downloaded every time again (testet with FF only).

[image]

Can I do anything about that? If not, that would mean to discard the object-approach.

**I DON'T WANT TO USE JAVASCRIPT.**

Comment: You can create one master SVG at the top of the page containing all of your shapes as symbols, and then reference the symbols in a `use` tag in `svg` tags throughout the page.

Check out the `use` documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/use

Comment: does the http server indicate that the object is cacheable?

Comment: @RobertLongson the SVGs are cached but every `<object>` sends its own request (and gets `304 not modified`). Even if I test it on a local test the images are rendered only after a short delay (which would not be too much of a problem, but the multiple requests are)

Comment: @sean that's sounds interesting but has less browser support, for example IE9-11 can't handle it (without JS)

Comment: @musicman IE9-11 can't handle `use` elements with external URIs, but they should be able to reference symbols in a master SVG inlined at the top of the page.